# How to read and excel cell address, when it is open and cell contains a formula

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an excel file. This excel file contains a formula on a cell address(example A10).
Now i open this excel file. One more thing I have installed an Add-Ins named Thomson Reuters in system. Through this Add-Ins cell address value changed periodically. How can i read the changed cell address value (without saving the excel file) using .net (c#).

Comment: The answer used to be DDE. I sincerely hope for your case that there are easier methods these days, because DDE was little fun. Back in 1998

Comment: Thomson Reuters is the name of a company, not an add-in.

Comment: "[In computing, Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE) is a method of interprocess communication under Microsoft Windows or OS/2. **It allows one program to subscribe to items made available by another program, for example a cell in a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet**, and be notified whenever a change of that item occurs. That method was partially superseded by Object Linking and Embedding (OLE), but remains used for simple interprocess communication tasks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange)"

Answer (score 0):

You Just open your excel file using interop code this will allow addin code to run side by side. then you can use cell value using interop calls.

```
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
                    xlApp.Visible = true;
                    Excel.Workbook newWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

xlApp.ActiveSheet.get_Range("A10", Type.Missing).Value2;
```